# mysql: check if all rows exists in other table

Tags: mysql

i have four tables in a mysql database, the schema is like this: 
[database_schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQZmv.png) & 
[the code on sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a33f07/4)

i want to select the `e_id`'s only when **all** rows from `ma_re.m_module` are included in `et_re.e_module` So if `et_re.e_module` row is {a,b,c,d} and `ma_re.mmodule` row is {a,d} it will select the `et_re.e_id` of that row.

> the `m_id` will be given as `x`.

so far i have trid this:

```
SELECT e_id FROM et_re JOIN ma_re
WHERE ma_re.m_id = x
AND ma_re.m_module = et_re.e_module
```

Comment: Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),
and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Also, if you setup a  http://sqlfiddle.com/ people will more happily help out

Comment: done, is it better now?

Comment: much better! :)

Comment: Didene, I deleted my answer, as clearly I had not understood what the requirement is. It will appear as unanswered once again and hopefully someone who understands what data you need to extract will help out

Comment: Thanks alot for your efforts <3

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood the question well, what it is confusing me is the following expression "when all rows from ma_re.m_module"

You have the tables with the following columns

```
et_re {
  e_id
  e_module
  e_note
}

ma_re {
  m_id
  m_module
  m_moyen
}
```

You can get the `e_id` from `et_re` where `et_re.e_module` equals `ma_re.m_module` with the following query (this would be the intersection between both tables)

```
SELECT DISTINCT et_re.e_id
  FROM et_re
  INNER JOIN ma_re ON et_re.e_module = ma_re.m_module;
```